# EmberJS - how to access parent controller from within child controller?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a `ProfilesController` and a `ProfileController` which represents a single Profile.

```
// Profiles listing
App.ProfilesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

});

// Single Profile representation
App.ProfileController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

    isActive: false,

    actions: {

        edit: function() {

            // TODO: disable all profiles
            // does not work ... parentController is undefined. pseudo code only!
            this.get('parentController.children').forEach(function(profile) {
                profile.set('isActive', false);
            });

            // enable current profile
            this.set('isActive', true);
        }
    }
});
```

Note that this is not the complete code, these 2 controllers have more code in my application and there is also a ProfileView which makes the profile listing possible.

The important part is how do I access the parent ProfilesController (the ArrayController) from within a ProfileController?

I have tried (in the edit action):

```
this.get('parent') // => undefined
this.get('parentController') // => null
this.get('target') // => null
```

**Edit**: meanwhile I went down the object tree and I came up with an incredibly hacky but working solution:

```
// disable all profiles
this.get('controllers.profiles.target._activeViews.profiles.0._childViews.0._childViews').forEach(function(childView) {
    childView.get('_childViews.0.controller').set('isActive', false);
});
```

It works until I change something in my templates structure I suppose. There has to be a cleaner way to do this :-D

**Edit 2**: To clarify a bit more, here is my Profiles Template, where `profiles` is a collection of Profile Models (not Controllers! Every model is represented by a Controller, since I have to store application state like current active profile etc.) :

```
{{#each profile in profiles}}
    {{view App.ProfileView profileBinding=profile}}
{{/each}}
```

and the ProfileView

```
App.ProfileView = Ember.View.extend({

     templateName: 'profiles/profile',

     init: function() {
         this._super();
         var profile = this.get('profile');

         // Here I explicitely create a ProfileController instance, 
         // otherwise ProfilesController would be used instead of ProfileController 
         // because in EmberJS by default the View's controller is always the parent controller
         this.set('controller', App.ProfileController.create());
         var controller = this.get('controller');
         controller.set('profile', profile);            
     }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `itemController` property in your `each` loop so that you don't have to manually create `ProfileController`s.

```
{{#each profile in profiles itemController="profile"}}
    {{view App.ProfileView profileBinding=profile}}
{{/each}}
```

Then you can use `needs` to make sure that a reference to the `ProfilesController` is injected into each `ProfileController`.  You'd use `this.get('controllers.profiles')` to access the `ArrayController` itself.  If you're doing things The Ember Way, you'd want to access the `content` property of that controller (`this.get('controllers.profiles.content')`).  It looks like you're not doing it The Ember Way, and instead have the collection to the `profiles` property of that controller instead of to the `content` property.  In that case you'd use `this.get('controllers.profiles.profiles')`.  The first instance of `profiles` gets the `ProfilesController`, the second instance gets the `profiles` property that is set on that controller.

```
App.ProfileController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['profiles'],
    actions: {
        edit: function() {

            this.get('controllers.profiles.profiles').forEach(function(profile) {
                profile.set('isActive', false);
            });

            // enable current profile
            this.set('isActive', true);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I tried that out - the problem is that in my case, controllers.profiles.profiles is the RecordArray of my Models, not an Array of the Controllers.

Comment: controllers.profiles.content and controllers.profiles.model is an empty Array. But I did change the whole thing to the "ember way" and it's much cleaner already (not creating the controller instances manually etc).

Comment: I don't know that it's possible to get a hold of an array of controllers like you're hoping to do.  You can move the `active` property into the model itself (just as a plain property, no need to use a `DS.attr`) and then update the models directly.  I've done this in an app and it works just fine.

Comment: At the beginning I had model properties for app state (isActive, isComplete, ...) but it had the drawback that the whole record got "dirty" when isActive was changed for example. With plain properties the model didnt get dirty but the properties were not populated when the record was loaded from the store...

Comment: but I will accept your answer now since you pointed out itemController, no more need to create controller instances on my own...much cleaner!

Comment: You can start with an initialized value by just setting it in the model definition.  `isActive : false` instead of `isActive : DS.attr('boolean')`

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to make it implicit (like in any other language to use super) or is it sufficient to name the controllers you want to access explicit?

See this link: http://eviltrout.com/2013/02/04/ember-pre-1-upgrade-notes.html

In your case it would be:

```
App.ProfileController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['profiles'],
    actions: {
        edit: function() {

            this.get('controllers.profiles').forEach(function(profile) {
                profile.set('isActive', false);
            });

            // enable current profile
            this.set('isActive', true);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: unfortunately this.get('controllers.profiles').children gives me undefined. (the 'needs' was already present in my controller as I need it for other things)

Comment: Ups sorry you don't need the "children" parameter anymore.
this.get('controllers.profiles').forEach(function(profile) {profile.set('isActive', false);}); is sufficient. I changed it also in my answer above.

Comment: This throws no error but has no effect at all. The function in forEach() does not even execute ;-/

Comment: Please take a look at my edits - I did specify my structure a bit more.